# Why can't I compile any of my old or new project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Today I was trying to launch my VS, but got some issues.
After creating a new project I don't have the option to "Run", but only to "Attach"
Solution Explorer shows that the current solution has 0 projects. When I right click and try to add an existing project after selecting .csproj file error shows up as in the screenshot
I tried to update, repair, delate and reinstall vs but nothing helps, got the same problem with every solution

[image: screenshot]

The error message:

> The project file cannot be opened. Unable to locate the .NET SDK.
> Check that it is installed and that the version specified in
> global.json (if any) matches the installed version.

Comment: In the future, please provide all errors as text; search engines and blind people can't read a picture of an error.

Comment: @BlackThunder no, i tried with C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet and C:\Program Files\dotnet and nothing change, also i cant run dotnet command in cmd

Comment: and when i run dotnet --info on powershell its show me that no .net sdk were found and install, but i downloaded newest version from https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Comment: How about this one? [Visual Studio 2019 unable to locate .Net Core SDK](https://superuser.com/questions/1431833/visual-studio-2019-unable-to-locate-net-core-sdk)

Comment: I suggest launching the Visual Studio Installer and running the "Repair" option on your install. It looks like something got removed that VS depends upon.